# Foundation reveal doesn't recognise modal link

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation reveal for modals on a site, but when I click on the modal firing link, it doesn't see it as a modal and just see the anchor "#". The website is dev.birddartmouth.co.uk

Here's my outputted modal HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="item" data-reveal-id="292">
    <img src="http://dev.birddartmouth.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/096.jpg">
</a>

<div id="292" class="reveal-modal">
    <i class="close icon close-reveal-modal"></i>
    <div class="header">
        Bow tie neck silk overlay top/dress with sequin hem – cream, grey                                           <p>£0</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://dev.birddartmouth.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/096.jpg">
    </div>
</div><!-- /modal -->
```

The foundation.min.js and foundation.reveal.js files are both loaded in the head. I've followed the instructions on the foundation docs (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) - can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the code. You can try opening the modal manually using Jquery

```
<a href="#" class="item" data-reveal-id="292">
<img src="http://dev.birddartmouth.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/096.jpg" width="200" height="200">
```

```
<div id="292" class="reveal-modal"> <i class="close icon close-reveal-modal">x</i> //x for close button

    <div class="header">Bow tie neck silk overlay top/dress with sequin hem – cream, grey
        <p>£0</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://dev.birddartmouth.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/096.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
    $('#' + id).foundation('reveal', 'open');
});


$(document).on('click', '.close-reveal-modal', function () {

    $(this).parent().foundation('reveal', 'close');
});
```

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rFLE3/

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what I ended up doing and it now works.